# How do I choose which monitor displays the console of a ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-server

I have a ubuntu-server 20.04.4 LTS machine with a CPU with integrated graphics, and two monitors connected via mainboard HDMI and DVI. When I start the server, the console will always appear on the monitor connected via DVI, the HDMI monitor is always black. Even if only the HDMI monitor is connected, it will still stay black. I assume this is because ubuntu still tries to display the console on the DVI monitor, even if it's not connected.

I always want the console to appear on the HDMI monitor. How do I change ubuntu to display the console on the HDMI monitor?

I saw many posts about how to use xrandr to do this, but I don't have that installed an if I undestand correctly, this has to do with the window manager, which I don't have anyway because it's Ubuntu Server and not Ubuntu.

To be clear, I am not talking about what monitor is used during boot, I am talking about a fully booted and functional Ubuntu Server that is waiting for a login on it's local console.